# PHP - 2 MySQL Queries in One PHP Function

Tags: php, mysql

I have two functions that I am using 2 different queries. I need to make one function that will retrieve the number of views for an item. Below are the two functions:

```
public function products_views(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('products');
    $this->db->order_by('view_count', 'DESC');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}       



public function getViewCount($product_id) {
    $this->db->select('COUNT(*) AS cnt');
    $this->db->from(views);
    $this->db->where('product_id', $product_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->row()->cnt;
}
```

I want a query that will return all the total view count for each product from the views table and display all the products from the products table showing the total view count.

Comment: How are the tables related? I see there is a product_id in views but you have view_count in products. You should be able to consolidate with a join and group by.

Comment: combine the result of both queries in an array. And return that array.

Comment: both tables have product_id in them for the relation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `JOIN` for tables `products` and `views` connecting `products.id` with `views.product_id`. As a result, the request should look like this:

```
SELECT products.id, COUNT(views.id) as cnt 
FROM views JOIN product ON products.id = views.product_id 
GROUP BY views.product_id
```

You need to interpret this request using your active records.

Comment: Great, that works. What about if I want to show all products from the products table even the ones that don't have no view records in the views table?

Comment: replace `FROM views JOIN product` to `FROM product JOIN views` and group by products.id